# List the files by giving the directory and a part of the file name along with extension

Tags: python-3.x, file, directory

Efficient way of listing the files by giving the directory and part of the filename along with extension.

```
For Ex:- Directory = "/home/Dell/Projects/"
         File Name Starts with = "sample_"
         Extension = ".csv"
```

I may have the following files in the directory mentioned,

```
1. "/home/Dell/Projects/sample_1.csv"
2. "/home/Dell/projects/sample_2019_01_04.csv"
3. "/home/Dell/Projects/sample_2.pkl"
4. "/home/Dell/Projects/sample_3.txt"
```

Out of the above 4 files, I should get file.1 & file.2 from the above list in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the help of os & fnmatch libraries, the desired result can be obtained.

```
import os, fnmatch
listOfFiles = os.listdir('/home/Dell/Projects/')  
pattern = "sample_*.csv"  
for entry in listOfFiles:  
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(entry, pattern):
        print ("Entry :: ", entry)
```

The output will be,

```
Entry :: sample_1.csv
Entry :: sample_2019_01_04.csv
```